# Is there a way for finding details about the sent request from the Python urllib3 response object?

Tags: python, http, urllib3

I'm migrating a Python tool that sends HTTP requests using requests module to another whose APIs use urllib3. Most of the migration is transparent, but I'm having trouble to get information about the sent request.

When using requests module, I just retrieve that information by getting the PreparedRequest object from the response. E.g.:

```
import requests

... (response generated)

request_method = response.request.method
```

However, urllib3 response objects don't seem to have an attribute/method to get the request object. Is there a way to retrieve that information from the urllib3 response?